# Wordpress random post link for same catergory

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, hyperlink, categories

I'm using a random post link plugin located here.
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/random-post-link

It works fin accept the link directs you to a random post in any category. I need it to direct to the same category. I found this code below it lets you chose 1 category.

```
function my_random_post_args($args) {

$args['category_name'] = 'cat-slug-here';

return $args;
}
add_filter('random_post_args', 'my_random_post_args');
```

This code was placed in the functions.php and it works accept I do not want to use just one cat i need it to be for all my categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function and **show the first category name only** in you random post function:

```
function my_random_post_args($args) {

$category = get_the_category(); 

$args['category_name'] = $category[0]->slug;

return $args;
}
add_filter('random_post_args', 'my_random_post_args');
```